# npm-run-all with ng build --watch

Tags: angular, npm-scripts

I have an angular 8 workspace with 2 projects:

- a library (my-library)
- a showcase for library testing

In my `package.json` I have something like

```
"lib:assets": "symlink-dir projects/my-library/assets dist/my-library/assets",
"lib:build": "ng build my-library && npm run lib:assets",
"lib:build-watch": "ng build my-library --watch",
"lib:watch": "npm-run-all -s lib:build-watch lib:assets"
```

But the `npm run lib:watch` is not working like I'd like.  It is running first `lib:assets` and only after `lib:build-watch`

The problem is that the library build is first erasing the dist folder.  So I'd like to build (and watch) first and only after make the link to the assets.

Is there a solution ?